# when shutting down linux systemd sends multiple sigterm signals to my application

Tags: c++, linux, systemd

I have setup a signal handler like shown below in c++ for an application that is designed to run on linux:

Setup the signal handler to call a static function:

```
// Setup the SIGNTERM signal handler for kill/pkill or systemd terminate
if (signal(SIGTERM, manager_signal_handler) == SIG_ERR)
{
    ERROR << "Failed to add signal SIGTERM to signal handler with error code: " << std::strerror(errno) << ENDL;
}
```

The static signal handler - which calls the class instance member function

```
static dds_manager_base *p_this_dds_manager_base = nullptr;
static void dds_manager_signal_handler(int signum)
{
    if (p_this_manager_base)
    {
        DEBUG << "static manager_signal_handler calling: p_this_manager_base->signal_handler\n";
        p_this_manager_base->signal_handler(signum);
    }
    else
    {
        ERROR << "manager_signal_handler - manager pointer not set\n";
    }
}
```

Member function - handles the signal:

```
void dds_manager_base::signal_handler(int signum)
{
    DEBUG << "dds_manager_base::signal_handler - received signal: " << signum << ENDL;
    // Termination actions - can take 5-10 seconds...
}
```

I am using `sytemctnl powerdown` to shutdown linux (which stops the service my application is running in). What I notice is that my application receives 2 or even 3 SIGTERM signals about 500ms apart.

I can handle this situation, but what I was expecting is 1 SIGTERM, followed by a SIGABRT maybe 90 seconds later if my application does not terminate within that time-limit.

My issue is that once I handle the signal in some cases my application has terminated fast enough that my class no longer exists and I get a core dump because the signal_handler() function is no longer there. So I  had the idea to return the signal to the `default behaviour signal(SIGTERM, SIG_DFL);` once I haev handled the signal - but since systemd is calling SIGTERM more then once on the second call `std::exit()` (I believe this is the default behaviour) is called and terminates my applcation before it can gracefully shutdown.

Here is my service/unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Invoke script to start the corvus application
After = network.target mnt-appdata.mount

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/mnt/appdata/deploy/services/start_module.sh ${SYS_NUM} ${DDS_NUM}

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You can see that the script `start_module.sh` is call - this is what then runs my applciation by doing: `./my-application &`

So my questions are:
 - Why do I get more then one SIGTERM and so close together?
 - What can I do to solve this behaviour?

Comment: Not strictly related to your problem, but if your `ERROR` or `DEBUG` are C++ streams or similar, you can't use them in your signal handler. There's only [a very restricted set](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) of POSIX syscalls and C library functions you can use in signal handlers, which notably do not include any standard C and C++ facilities for IO or memory allocation. Since it's pretty much impossible to do anything meaningful in a signal handler, all you want to do there is to raise a `sig_atomic_t` flag and let the main program handle the shutdown.

Comment: Why not just set a flag before initiating the the SIGTERM function. If the flag is already set, let the signal handler do nothing. Protect the flag with a mutex, or use a `std::atomic`.

Comment: After the first shutdown signal is sent by systemd, how long does it take you app to shut down? Sysemd has a mechanism that it just wants to ensure your app is down before the poweroff is sent. (there are some setting you can set to prevent poweroff  from proceeding unless you app and until your app ends releasing the lock preventing powerdow. There isn't anything wrong with systemd sending a signal to check, and if you have begun the shutdown process -- why can't you just ignore them?

Comment: @super using a mutex in a signal handler is the best way to get a deadlock between the signal handler and the "regular" code. Also, `std::atomic<T>` isn't async-signal safe unless the given `std::atomic` you are using `is_lock_free() == true` (and I'm not even sure it's guaranteed). signals != threads, don't mix up their stuff. Use `sig_atomic_t` and be happy with it.

Comment: Also: is your application multithreaded?

Comment: @MatteoItalia ah, that is really interesting info - thanks :)

Comment: @super this is what I basically ended up doing (I think I mentioned that I can handle it) but I want to know why this occurs - but still, that is a helpful comment thanks

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I can ignore them - but I want to understand *why* this happens. Maybe it is just very normal! - but I understood that it should only send it *once* at the start and then a SIGSBRT after a timeout...?

Comment: @MatteoItalia yes it is multi-threaded - still catching up on all the extra pointers here :o

Answer (score 2):

> What I notice is that my application receives 2 or even 3 `SIGTERM` signals about 500ms apart.

That is not the behaviour of `systemd`, you may like to verify your observations.

See [`man systemd.kill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.kill.5.html) for full details:

> ```
>    KillMode=
> ```
>
> Specifies how processes of this unit shall be killed. One of control-group, process, mixed, none.
>
> If set to control-group, all remaining processes in the control group of this unit will be killed on unit stop (for services: after the stop command is executed, as configured with ExecStop=). If set to process, only the main process itself is killed. If set to mixed, the SIGTERM signal (see below) is sent to the main process while the subsequent SIGKILL signal (see below) is sent to all remaining processes of the unit's control group. If set to none, no process is killed. In this case, only the stop command will be executed on unit stop, but no process be killed otherwise. Processes remaining alive after stop are left in their control group and the control group continues to exist after stop unless it is empty.
>
> Processes will first be terminated via SIGTERM (unless the signal to send is changed via KillSignal=). Optionally, this is immediately followed by a SIGHUP (if enabled with SendSIGHUP=). If then, after a delay (configured via the TimeoutStopSec= option), processes still remain, the termination request is repeated with the SIGKILL signal (unless this is disabled via the SendSIGKILL= option). See kill(2) for more information.
>
> Defaults to control-group.

Comment: I have read this page which is why I thought I get a SIGTERM (as per third paragraph) followed after a timeout by SIGKILL (actually I wrote SIGABRT - I got that wrong). But I can confirm / verify every time I get multiple SIGTERMs in my application... I am baffled by it

Comment: Then there's something stranger going on... I wrote a [somewhat minimal test program involving threads](https://bitbucket.org/mitalia/test-signals-service/src/master/test-signals-service.c) (I had doubts about the "SIGTERM sent to all processes in the control group" thing), and I cannot see the behavior you are describing when stopping the service through systemd.

Comment: @code_fodder It could be receiving one `SIGTERM` per thread then. Try using `KillMode=process`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia could it be to do with starting the application via a script: service -> script -> `app &`. So the service calls start script and then the script runs the app in the background (apersand)

Comment: @code_fodder The script should probably `exec` the executable, so that there is no intermediate script and use `Type=simple`, see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Comment: Why is the script needed/is launching the main program in background? Can't you just put your "real" executable as target of `ExecStart`? In a `simple` or `idle` service it's expected that the launched program will stay running.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I will try both of your suggestions, thanks : )

Comment: @MatteoItalia actually the script does things like start drivers and other periphery applications that the main application needs to talk to. Yes, they could all be lots of services in their own right in some heirachy of services! - but that seemed much more work to maintain and does not appear to benefit me for teh effort (unless it is causing this issue?)

Comment: @code_fodder That explains the discrepancy in the expected and actual behaviour. Your script should at the very least `exec` your executable so that `systemd` sends the signals to your executable daemon process, rather than your shell script. Otherwise you have to use `trap` in your shell script to forward the signals to your executable, but to make that work correctly you need to understand exactly what you are doing, process groups and session leader, controlling terminal and other important tiny details like that.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin while I agree in general, it should still somewhat work as it is... given that the default is to send `SIGTERM` to all processes in the control group, the process should still receive it - and indeed it does, just too many times.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I suspect `systemd` sends `SIGTERM` to every _thread_ in the group, rather than _process_, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: that's what I suspected, but then I tried with this test program https://bitbucket.org/mitalia/test-signals-service/src/master/test-signals-service.c, and the signal was delivered only to the main thread. Unless some strange heuristics kicks in when the process that was originally started doesn't exist anymore... after all `GuessMainPID` is a thing that exists in systemd (although probably unrelated to this specific problem).

Comment: @MatteoItalia I am going to have to start to break-down my setup to see what is causing the multiple SIGTERMs until I end up with something similar to your example. Somewhere between the two I must find the cause (I think).